# Visual Studio 2022 not respecting NuGet.config repositoryPath setting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to override the default nuget package output location for a C# project (bin/Debug).  I have checked the settings in %appdata%/NuGet/NuGet.config, and I see the following:

```
<add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Users\david\nuget-packages\" />
```

This is great, it is exactly where I want NuGet packages placed.  Unfortunately, this setting is not being respected by Visual Studio 2022. I have enabled the "Generate NuGet package on build" setting in VS.

I also tried the outdated, accepted answer found here: [change output directory of nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893005/change-output-directory-of-nuget-package)

Which mentions adding `<PackageOutputDir>C:\Users\david\nuget-packages</PackageOutputDir>` as a child to PropertyGroup in the relevant .csproj file.  Did not work, VS2022 continues to output to the Solutions Debug directory :(

EDIT:  Running the command dotnet pack -o C:\Users\david\nuget-packages\ works, but was hoping I would not have to run this command every time I update/build my project...

Comment: Why you would want to do this?

Comment: Raise an issue with them

Comment: The only feasible way is to raise a bug, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Because I don't want to manually move the outputted .nupkg file from the solution folder to my local nuget package repository folder every time I make a change in my library and rebuild.  I use that local folder so that my other projects can easily pull in local packages, from one centralized location.  I am trying to automate  this process, and being able to change the output folder is the simplest solution.  Hope that makes sense :)  Obviously many others use this functionality (probably for the same reason as me), or it would not be a setting in NuGet.config :P

Comment: @stuartd So this is a legit issue then?  I wasn't sure if I was overlooking something, or if it is a bug.